# Xcode: How to compile for i386, armv7, armv7s, and arm64?

Tags: xcode, compilation

I want to compile my application for i386, armv7, armv7s, and arm64. The only options I see are i386, armv7, and armv7s OR armv7, armv7s, and arm64. Is there any way to get all 4?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure i386, armv7, armv7s and arm64 all appear under "Valid Archictures" ***AND*** the "architectures" build settings for your project.

Here's a screenshot of the Build Settings panel for a test project I just created.

I'll need to add "i386" under "Valid Architectures" and then I'll also need to modify "Architectures" (a few lines above "Valid Architectures") to match.

[image: Valid Architectures]

Answer (score 0):

I find that you need to make sure you have the right Build Target, also.  In this case, probably "Generic iOS Device" would be most suitable since you want to build for various architecture.  If I only select specific target then it might not build all of the requested target.

[Set Generic iOS Build Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpfA7.png)